# How to use camera in background in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to use the camera in background mode for continuous taking images.but as per apple documentation, we could not use the camera in background mode. Is there any alternate solution for fetching camera without opening application.My task is that When user clicked one button, app should be close and taking images continuously.Could you please any one guide me to do this task?

Comment: First thing it's not possible and by chance you did it then surely Apple reject your app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/interruptionreason/videodevicenotavailableinbackground) say it, it's not possible:

> Camera usage is prohibited while in the background.

And I don't think there is any way to do that.

Comment: what about picture in picture mode at least? as in android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture in this case it's not background, because we can see a small window with camera preview?

Comment: it seems, in PIP mode it's also not possible, it's only allowed for FaceTime app (but it's private API) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770781/7767664